# Oracle Virtual Server OEL vm fails to start - kernel panic on cpu identify

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I am in the process of following a guide to setup various oracle vm templates, so far I have installed OVS 2. 2 and got the OVM Manager working, imported the template for OEL5U5 and created a vm from it.. the problem comes when starting that vm.

The log in the OVMM console shows the following;

```
Update VM Status - Running
Configure CPU Cap
Set CPU Cap: failed:<Exception: failed:<Exception: ['xm', 'sched-credit', '-d',  
'32_EM11g_OVM', '-c', '0'] => Error: Domain '32_EM11g_OVM' does not exist.

StackTrace:
File "/opt/ovs-agent-2.3/OVSXXenVMConfig.py", line 2531, in xen_set_cpu_cap
run_cmd(args=['xm',
File "/opt/ovs-agent-2.3/OVSCommons.py", line 92, in run_cmd
raise Exception('%s => %s' % (args, err))
```

The xend.log shows;

```
[2012-11-12 16:42:01 7581] DEBUG (DevController:139) Waiting for devices vtpm
[2012-11-12 16:42:01 7581] INFO (XendDomain:1180) Domain 32_EM11g_OVM (3) unpaused. 
[2012-11-12 16:42:03 7581] WARNING (XendDomainInfo:1907) Domain has crashed: name=32_EM11g_OVM id=3.
[2012-11-12 16:42:03 7581] ERROR (XendDomainInfo:2041) VM 32_EM11g_OVM restarting too fast (Elapsed time: 11.377262 seconds). Refusing to restart to avoid loops .>
[2012-11-12 16:42:03 7581] DEBUG (XendDomainInfo:2757) XendDomainInfo.destroy: domid=3
[2012-11-12 16:42:12 7581] DEBUG (XendDomainInfo:2230) Destroying device model
[2012-11-12 16:42:12 7581] INFO (image:553) 32_EM11g_OVM device model terminated
```

I have set_on_crash="preserve" in the vm.cfg and have then run xm create -c to get the console screen while booting and this is the log of what happens..

```
Started domain 32_EM11g_OVM (id=4)
Bootdata ok (command line is ro root=LABEL=/ )
Linux version 2.6.18-194.0.0.0.3.el5xen (mockbuild@build.example.com) (gcc 
version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)) #1 SMP Mon Mar 29 18:27:00 EDT 2010
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Xen: 0000000000000000 - 0000000180800000 (usable)>
No mptable found.
Built 1 zonelists. Total pages: 1574912
Kernel command line: ro root=LABEL=/
Initializing CPU#0
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 32768 bytes)
Xen reported: 1600.008 MHz processor.
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
Software IO TLB disabled
Memory: 6155256k/6299648k available (2514k kernel code, 135548k reserved, 1394k data, 184k init)
Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 4006.42 BogoMIPS (lpj=8012858)
Security Framework v1.0.0 initialized
SELinux: Initializing.
selinux_register_security: Registering secondary module capability
Capability LSM initialized as secondary
Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
CPU: L1 I Cache: 64K (64 bytes/line), D cache 16K (64 bytes/line)
CPU: L2 Cache: 2048K (64 bytes/line)
general protection fault: 0000 [1] SMP
last sysfs file:
CPU 0
Modules linked in:
Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.18-194.0.0.0.3.el5xen #1
RIP: e030:[ffffffff80271280] [ffffffff80271280] identify_cpu+0x210/0x494
RSP: e02b:ffffffff80643f70 EFLAGS: 00010212
RAX: 0040401000810008 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00000000c001001f
RDX: 0000000000404010 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000005
RBP: ffffffff8063e980 R08: 0000000000000025 R09: ffff8800019d1000
R10: 0000000000000026 R11: ffff88000102c400 R12: 0000000000000000
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
FS: 0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffffff805d2000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS: e033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000
Process swapper (pid: 0, threadinfo ffffffff80642000, task ffffffff804f4b80)
Stack: 0000000000000000 ffffffff802d09bb ffffffff804f4b80 0000000000000000
0000000021100800 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffff8064cb00
0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Call Trace:
[ffffffff802d09bb] kmem_cache_zalloc+0x62/0x80
[ffffffff8064cb00] start_kernel+0x210/0x224
[ffffffff8064c1e5] _sinittext+0x1e5/0x1eb
Code: 0f 30 b8 73 00 00 00 f0 0f ab 45 08 e9 f0 00 00 00 48 89 ef
RIP [ffffffff80271280] identify_cpu+0x210/0x494
RSP ffffffff80643f70
0 Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

clear as mud to me.

are there any other logs that will help me?

I have now deployed another vm from the same template and used the default vm settings rather than adding more memory etc - I get exactly the same error.